# Nginx headers parsing

Tags: nginx, json

For example, I have nginx and incoming JSON header:

```
{
  "orgs" : {
    "first_org_roles": ["role_a_r", "role_b_r", "role_c_r"],
    "second_org_roles": ["role_d_r", "role_e_r", "role_f_r"]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to parse it into an array:

```
["role_a_r", "role_b_r", "role_c_r", "role_d_r", "role_e_r", "role_f_r"]
```

and set it as a header in nginx?

Comment: This is not a header, it's JSON data. And it has nothing to do with nginx.

Comment: If course it can be parsed that way. But to say how people need to know what you want to use to do it. What scripting/programming language/tool you want to use.

Comment: No, it's exactly header looks like json. My authentication service generates this header and sends me. And I should parse it and forward it further, to my services.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just read it again and realized I missed some parts. Some details are still missing though. are these headers that you get by a client and want to send it to some backend you are proxying for? Or the other way around?

Comment: Yes, my component has authentication by headers, but incoming header from my authentication service sends me this json with roles and it's incompatible. I wanna try to parse it with nginx.